# Opengeo : Add new server dialog doesn't show up

Tags: boundless-suite

While trying to follow the tutorial of Opengeo for creating a new application, I am getting stuck on one of the first steps: namely the addition of a new server dialog.
(http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/apps/clientsdkintro/viewer/addnewserver.html)

I added the following lines in my app.js and restarted my server application. Unfortunately I cannot get the "Add a New Server ..." line as described in the tutorial when adding new layers.

`* @require overrides/override-ext-ajax.js
  ...
proxy="proxy/?url="`

The full content of my app.js is available at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6899291

Note that I am starting my application using the following command on a Linux machine where Opengeo was installed : `suite-sdk debug -g http://localhost:8080/geoserver myapp`

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your full app.js file? Maybe use a https://gist.github.com and share the link here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah this one is an easy one. You have added the proxy setting to the wrong part of the the gxp.viewer configuration.

Where you have:

```
var app = new gxp.Viewer({
portalConfig: {
layout: "border",
region: "center",
proxy: "proxy/?url=",
```

Instead put:

```
var app = new gxp.Viewer({
proxy: "proxy/?url=",
portalConfig: {
layout: "border",
region: "center",
```

At the moment you are adding the setting to gxp.Viewer.portalConfig not gxp.Viewer

I tested this quickly and it worked on my sytem with te latest version of the OpenGEO SDK